# How to get MySQL query AND return all results when no input has been entered

Tags: mysql

So i'm trying to make a reasonably basic search functionality.

What i've got so far is 4 inputs. The search string, and three numerically stored drop down lists. The user is to enter the text, and select any, or none, of the dropdowns to narrow their search.

The problem is that whenever i try to adapt my query to include more than just text fields i cannot get it to work as i want it.

What i want to do is to treat all statements like the LIKE ones currently are, where if no text is found, then all results are returned. What i'm getting right now with the two OR statements for each sub-query is that when the user doesn't select a value from the three dropdowns the query fails and an error occurs. How would I go about fixing this?

```
SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle, CoverImage, CreationDate, date_format(CreationDate, '%D %M %Y') AS 'Date', Visible 
        FROM (SELECT a.ArticleID, a.ArticleTitle, a.CoverImage, a.CreationDate, null as Visible, a.GenreID, a.Score FROM articles AS a
        JOIN article_game ON a.ArticleID = article_game.ArticleID 
        JOIN game ON article_game.GameID = game.GameID
        JOIN genre ON a.GenreID = genre.GenreID
        JOIN article_console ON a.ArticleID = article_console.ArticleID
        JOIN console ON article_console.ConsoleID = console.ConsoleID
        WHERE (
            a.ArticleTitle LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            OR game.GameName LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            OR genre.Genre LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            OR console.Console LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            )
        AND genre.GenreID = ".$G."
        AND a.Score = ".$S."
        UNION
        SELECT ta.ArticleID, ta.ArticleTitle, ta.CoverImage, ta.CreationDate, ta.Visible, ta.GenreID, ta.Score FROM temp_article AS ta
        JOIN temp_article_game ON ta.ArticleID = temp_article_game.ArticleID 
        JOIN game ON temp_article_game.GameID = game.GameID
        JOIN genre ON ta.GenreID = genre.GenreID
        JOIN temp_article_console ON ta.ArticleID = temp_article_console.ArticleID
        JOIN console ON temp_article_console.ConsoleID = console.ConsoleID
        WHERE (
            ta.Visible = true AND ta.ArticleTitle LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            OR game.GameName LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            OR genre.Genre LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
            OR console.Console LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                )
        AND genre.GenreID = ".$G."
        AND ta.Score = ".$S."   
        ) a
        ORDER BY CreationDate desc"
```

Where $G and $S correlate to what is found in $_POST['GenreID'] and $_POST['Score'] respectively, both of which do not have to have a value and should be able to be left as *None* with a value of "". (currently this is what breaks the statement).

As genre is an ID and score is a definite integer, i don't want to use the like clause to fix this as this would presumably return too many values like "12", "112", "122", "123" etc which is useless when you're only looking for one genre, for example.

Comment: Set a 'default' value when the 'input' is empty that will ensure the test is 'true' for every row?

Comment: That works, to an extent, but still doesn't allow me to find all "articles" when the conditions don't match.

For example, im using -1 as my "blank" values for all categories except the string itself as a ID, or score can never be a negative value. However because it can never be a negative value, no results are found because of the AND condition requiring the genre.GenreID = .. to be considered, even if it's blank. 

However, i found a workaround. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was to stop treating the MySQL query like a query and to start treating it like a string. Thinking of it in this manner meant i could concatenate strings by using if statements. Here is the resulting string collection which solves my question.

```
$SearchQuery = "SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle, CoverImage, CreationDate, date_format(CreationDate, '%D %M %Y') AS 'Date', Visible 
                FROM (SELECT a.ArticleID, a.ArticleTitle, a.CoverImage, a.CreationDate, null as Visible, a.GenreID, a.Score FROM articles AS a
                LEFT JOIN article_game ON a.ArticleID = article_game.ArticleID 
                LEFT JOIN game ON article_game.GameID = game.GameID
                LEFT JOIN genre ON a.GenreID = genre.GenreID
                LEFT JOIN article_console ON a.ArticleID = article_console.ArticleID
                LEFT JOIN console ON article_console.ConsoleID = console.ConsoleID
                WHERE (
                    a.ArticleTitle LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    OR game.GameName LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    OR genre.Genre LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    OR console.Console LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    )";
    if (!empty($G) && ($G != -1)){
        $SearchQuery .= "AND genre.GenreID = ".$G." ";
    }
    if (!empty($S) && ($S != -1)){
        $SearchQuery .= "AND a.Score = ".$S." ";
    }

$SearchQuery .= "UNION
                SELECT ta.ArticleID, ta.ArticleTitle, ta.CoverImage, ta.CreationDate, ta.Visible, ta.GenreID, ta.Score FROM temp_article AS ta
                LEFT JOIN temp_article_game ON ta.ArticleID = temp_article_game.ArticleID 
                LEFT JOIN game ON temp_article_game.GameID = game.GameID
                LEFT JOIN genre ON ta.GenreID = genre.GenreID
                LEFT JOIN temp_article_console ON ta.ArticleID = temp_article_console.ArticleID
                LEFT JOIN console ON temp_article_console.ConsoleID = console.ConsoleID
                WHERE (
                    ta.Visible = true AND ta.ArticleTitle LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    OR game.GameName LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    OR genre.Genre LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    OR console.Console LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                    )";
    if (!empty($G) && ($G != -1)){
        $SearchQuery .= "AND genre.GenreID = ".$G." ";
    }
    if (!empty($S) && ($S != -1)){
        $SearchQuery .= "AND ta.Score = ".$S." ";
    }
$SearchQuery .= ") a
            ORDER BY CreationDate desc";
```

This gives me the same result, but ignores $G or $S if their value is -1. The !empty checks on the same values ensure that the query always works, otherwise the post values are considered the first time the page is loaded, breaking the query by having "AND genre.GenreID = AND a.Score = " in it with no values to check against.

Comment: Explain what you mean by security issues. Can you give me an example? Would there potentially be any issues in my code as it is? Why would there be any difference between it all being written as one string, or if it's being concatenated? (unless you left vulnerabilities in the code, obviously).

As it is, this code is as a project, no purpose, no client, so it 'doesn't really matter', but i'd still like to know for future.

Comment: So you were talking about problems such as sql injection from unsecure strings being interpreted in the query then?

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it, i know how. I'm asking if that is what you meant.

Comment: Well thanks for the extra help, maybe it'll help somebody. In this case it's not needed as numbers cannot be manipulated directly, only through drop downs. Sorry i was confusing, but i'd always welcome too much help ever too little :)

Comment: i did nothing useful here. i always  try and learn something from each encounter. thank you

Comment: Unrelated things can still be useful, even if, in this case, nothing was. Doesn't mean you should ever give up. I only knew about SQL injection because somebody added it in a previous question as an unrelated helpful comment :)